# Duplicates removal with MySQL query

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I created a MySQL table  and that has been filling up in the last couple of weeks.
Now I found out that some rows contains duplicates

The fields `deviceId, counter1, counter2` together are a unique index. However I cannot ALTER the Table as there are duplicates. So my quesiton is how to remove these duplicates using a MySQL query

Entries have duplicates on `counter1` and / or `counter2`

```
*deviceId      ts                  counter1    counter2*
device001     2018-06-11 10:18:51     1           2
device001     2018-06-11 10:23:10     1           2
device002     2018-06-12 08:27:33     321         20
device002     2018-06-12 09:49:13     321         20
```

And from these duplicates 1 should be removed. Any suggestions on how to do this simple? I have tried the following:

**Created a copy of the Table**

```
CREATE TABLE sp_data_copy LIKE sp_data_orig;
INSERT sp_data_copy SELECT * FROM sp_data_orig;
```

**Select and delete from copy Table**

```
DELETE FROM sp_data_copy
WHERE ts IN (
    SELECT ts 
    FROM sp_data_orig
    GROUP BY counter1, counter2
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

But obviously it has not worked for me. Hope you have some suggestions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that all the columns? Is there no primary key, or other column that is unique?

Comment: Please do `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` on the table in question. I think you're saying the three columns *should* be a unique index, but you can't alter the table to make that true. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I have NO primary key at this moment and would like to add a unique index to error out duplicates.

Comment: 'CREATE TABLE `sp_data` (
  `devId` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `ts` datetime NOT NULL,
  `counter 1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `counter2` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `batteryLevel` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'

Comment: I read thru the answer you referred - however it does not solve my duplicate issue. Have edited and updated my question above